# Avoid blur between SVG linear gradients stop-color offsets (Chrome)

Tags: svg

FireFox displays what I would expect: solid blocks of color with sharp edges between each stop-color. However, Chrome has blurry edges between stop-colors even though there is little or no gap between the offset, regardless of using decimals (0 to 1) or percentages (0% - 100%).

Is this something I have to live with, or is there a way to get Chrome to behave how I would expect?

Example is simplified and will be used as full-screen background:

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='900' height='900' viewBox='0 0 100% 100%'>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='a' x1='0' x2='0' y1='0' y2='100%' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
      <stop offset='0.1999' stop-color='#F00'/>
      <stop offset='0.2' stop-color='#FFF'/>
      <stop offset='0.4999' stop-color='#FFF'/>
      <stop offset='0.5' stop-color='#b2b2b2'/>
      <stop offset='0.8' stop-color='#b2b2b2'/>
      <stop offset='0.8' stop-color='#000'/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill='url(#a)' width='100%' height='100%'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Let me add that Illustrator, MS Edge, and FireFox display sharp transitions, while Chrome and Opera have blurry transitions.